# NotSupportedException when using list as parameter for EF

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, devexpress

Im using a Devexpress AspxGridView control to display some rows and fetch the values the user selects so I can populate another control with Entity Framework 5.

I get the list of selected CustomerNos here:

```
Dim CustomerNos = CustomerGrid.GetSelectedFieldValues("CustomerNo").ToList()
```

Then I try to fetch all the rows which have matching CustomerNos in table CustomerDeliveryPoint

```
 Dim t = (From a In db.CustomerDeliveryPoint Where CustomerNos.Contains(a.CustomerNo) Select a).ToList()
```

Thats when i get the exception error saying it cant create type system.object. Only primitive types or enumerables are supported in this context.

Comment: what is the type of a.CustomerNo, what is the type of CustomerNos ?

Comment: They both should be strings. As long as CustomerGrid.GetSelectedFielVaules dosent do something strang with it.

Comment: This works:  'Dim c As SpiderWebShop.Data.CustomerDeliveryPoint = New SpiderWebShop.Data.CustomerDeliveryPoint()  c.CustomerNo = "900353"  Dim CustomerNos = CustomerGrid.GetSelectedFieldValues("CustomerNo").ToList()  Dim val = CustomerNos.Contains(c.CustomerNo)'

Comment: can you try `Dim CustomerNos As List(Of String) = ...`

Comment: @tschmit007 Its says I cant convert type List (Of Object) to List (of String)

Comment: imho, that'is why the linq query fails

Comment: @tschmit007 It only fails in the linq query. Doing `Dim t = New CustomerDeiliveryPoint()`  and setting `t.CustomerNo="12345"` `CustomerNos.Contains(t.CustomerNo)`works and evaulates correctly

Comment: is something like `Dim CustomerNos = CustomerGrid.GetSelectedFieldValues("CustomerNo").ToList().Select(Function(x) x.ToString()).ToList() ` doable in vb.

Comment: It is impossible to cast the List(Of Object) to List(Of String) directly. It is not necessary to add the Select function, if your List<Of Object> actually contains only string values. Use the Cast(Of String) method, in this case. CustomerNos.Cast(Of String)()